# how to run containerized console app on Azure?

Tags: containers, console-application, azure-appservice

I have a containerized a console app which run as a scheduler app and performe some logic at specific time. I tried to run it as an Azure App service but getting below error

```
2022-03-30T19:10:29.209Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container one-site-scheduler-app_0_d429ab9d. Elapsed time = 209.8994308 sec
2022-03-30T19:10:45.377Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container one-site-scheduler-app_0_d429ab9d. Elapsed time = 226.067164 sec
2022-03-30T19:10:49.746Z ERROR - Container scheduler-app_0_d for site one-site-scheduler-app did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.4276536 sec
2022-03-30T19:10:49.901Z ERROR - Container scheduler-app_0_d didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-03-30T19:10:49.977Z INFO  - Stopping site scheduler-app because it failed during startup.
```

Although before it stops the container I see the logs from the scheduler app.

I am not sure what am I missing here.

I tried following [https://ameshram57.medium.com/azure-app-service-container-container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-e2e653d867fe#:\~:text=if%20you%20are%20getting%20%E2%80%9C%20ERROR,we%20map%20port%20in%20docker](https://ameshram57.medium.com/azure-app-service-container-container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-e2e653d867fe#:%5C%7E:text=if%20you%20are%20getting%20%E2%80%9C%20ERROR,we%20map%20port%20in%20docker).

this article but no luck.

Comment: [Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168746/container-didn39t-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-80.html) and [Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46401)

Comment: my console app doesn't have any web server running. The console app connects a cosmos db, fetch the data, performs some logic and then save the calculated value back to the cosmod db. These steps are scheduled using corn. I am using Quartz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learn that Azure app service pings on port 80 by default to check if it gets any response, since my container just ran a console application it never responded to the ping from the app service. To fix that I converted my console app to a single point web app using webhostbuilder and followed the steps from the below,
https://nitishkaushik.com/what-is-webhostbuilder-in-asp-net-core/

This trick worked.